# Какое минимальное количество потоков может быть у одного процесса?

Tags: linux, многопоточность, процесс

Заранее извиняюсь за, возможно, глупый вопрос.
Читал про максимальное количество потоков у одного процесса в linux, и спонтанно возник вопрос, а какой минимум потоков может быть у процесса? Может ли процесс иметь ноль потоков?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Процесс должен иметь как минимум 1 поток.

Comment: Это функция main? Она создаёт тот самый поток?

Comment: Имеете в виду С/C++? Не могу точно быть уверен, так как с ним не работал, но если по аналогии с Java, то простым языком можно сказать и так. При запуске программы создаётся процесс, а функция main будет управлять основным потоком.

Comment: С помощью чего функция main управляет основным потоком? Если будет создано 10 потоков, кто ими будет управлять?

Comment: Если единственный поток процесса завершится, процесс будет завершен самой операционной системой. Нет смысла держать процесс с 0 потоков, он ничего не делает, и ничего не сможет сделать.

Comment: @defrag, "функция main()" в C/C++ ничем (в этом смысле) не управляет. Вы путаете синтаксис языка с концепциями/возможностями ОС, железа и т.д.

Comment: @Zergatul, нет, и не всегда. Вопрос, конечно же в практической ценности таких вырожденных случаев.

Comment: @PinkTux мои вопросы были для комментария выше, основанные на его тексте. `Вы путаете синтаксис языка с концепциями/возможностями ОС, железа и т.д.` - ну вы как-то совсем плохого мнения обо мне. Это же как перепутать сцепление с багажником.

Comment: @defrag, ну так вы ж путаете :)

Comment: @PinkTux ну... ладно, фиг со мной. А фраза "При запуске программы создаётся процесс, **а функция main будет управлять основным потоком**." я так понимаю - верная?

Comment: @defrag Вы правы, я ошибся

Comment: @defrag, нет, не верная. При чём тут вообще `main()`? Это только C-фича, уровня синтаксиса конкретного языка.

Comment: @PinkTux да, я в курсе. Вот и человек выше уже написал, что ошибся. Это можно больше не обсуждать :]

Comment: @0andriy, приведите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь пример (код), чтобы это можно было пощупать...

Comment: Рискну напомнить, что само понятие "Поток" было введено в стандарт POSIX.1-2001. Процессы в *NIX* системах были изначально. А вот "потоки" появились значительно позже. Т.е. процесс без потока - абсолютно нормальное явление.  Когда запускается программа, выполняется *fork*, затем - *exec*. Ни там ни там ни слова про потоки. Более того, что бы программа была способна работать с потоками, на этапе линковки необходимо указать флаг *-lpthread*. А без этого - никаких потоков.